# Is there a Guide to non alcoholic ice cream floats?

Tags: ice-cream

Is there a guide to making kid friendly ice cream floats? In other words no alcohol content. Note that I come at it from an Australian perspective so ice cream floats from places like Mexico might not be as relevant as a focus on Australia or the UK or the US.

This could be a book or something else like a Youtube channel.

Comment: I've never seen an alcoholic float.

Comment: @GdD [There is a bar/restaurant in my town](https://www.fountainonlocust.com/drink) whose reputation is based on alcoholic ice cream floats but, yes, I consider such things unusual myself but wouldn't mind having one.

Comment: I'm all up for trying one @Rob, vanilla ice cream with some Kahlua, or a sorbet based float with some Tequila, I can think of a load of possibilities I would not let my kids try. In any case this question is too broad, and is bordering on a recipe request, so off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

In the US, ice cream floats are simply ice cream and carbonated soda, and so are naturally kid friendly.

One of the most well known is the root beer float - vanilla ice cream and root beer. Another that seemed to trend some years ago was orange sherbet and cream soda.

The flavor combinations are endless. Use your imagination and fix what suits your taste.

Comment: ahhh memories...

Comment: @Max Yes! The good ol' days.

Comment: In Australia in the 1960's we called ice cream floats a "spider" because the ice cream forms a spidery pattern. You could walk into a milk bar [US dairy bar] and ask for a spider and they would make one for you. But now they wouldn't have a clue what one is!They would say do they crawl? lol

Comment: @Max Memories that can reside in your refrigerator and freezer.

Comment: Adding to this - my personal favourite was and still in Orange Soda (preferably Orange Crush) and Vanilla Ice Cream.

Comment: Another popular combination is cola with vanilla ice cream.  But, I'll still take mine with root beer, please.

Comment: Lots of good ones! I also used to make one with vanilla ice cream and chocolate fudge soda. Nostalgia hit and I'm picking up a 6 pack of that soda this weekend! It's been a really long time!